# How to not get end of line character using cin.get() in c++

Tags: c++, line, eol

so I know how to use `cin.get()` and how to use buffers or so I thought. Here is a sample program which gets n(number or rows) and m(number of columns) for a table. Then it gets n*m characters, saves them in an array and outputs them:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int n, m;
char in;
char a[100][100];
int main()
{
    cin >> n >> m;
    for(int i = 0;i < n; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j < m; ++j)
        {
            cin.get(in);
                a[i][j] = in;
            if(j == m - 1)
                cin.get();
        }
    }
for(int i = 0;i < n; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0;j < m; ++j)
    cout <<a[i][j];
    cout << endl;
}
    return 0;
}
```

This program seems to count some chars as end of lines. Can someone fix that and explain me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you sow us an input example ?

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` coupled with `using namespace std;` is a risky maneuver. It uses a non-standard header only intended for use with precompiled headers in g++ to include pretty much the entire Standard library. That's a lot of identifiers you could collide with; fortunately the `std` namespace prevents carnage. Except `using namespace std;` eliminates the need to specify the `std` namespace, creating a minefield of tens of thousands of identifiers with common names like `string`, `swap`, and `reverse` lurking and waiting for a chance to blow up your program.

Comment: performance note: `cout << endl;` is pretty expensive because along with the newline it forces a flush of the stream. If you need speed, `cout << '\n';` will be much faster. Worth doing anyway just out of general principles.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter n and m, cin.get() will start immediately at the char following the number, which could be a space or a new line. There might therefore be a shift between the input you expect and the input that you get. This causes every m chars to be ignored ieven if not a newline, and converseky, some newlines to be read instead of another char.

After your number extraction, it would be safer to cin.ignore() chars until the first new line.

Similarly, check for every nth char that you skip, if it is the newline that you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use cin if you do not want endl and space characters;

Just replace cin.get() with cin>>

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int n, m;
char in;
char a[100][100];
int main()
{
    cin >> n >> m;
    for(int i = 0;i < n; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j < m; ++j)
        {
            cin>>in;
                a[i][j] = in;
        }
    }
for(int i = 0;i < n; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0;j < m; ++j)
    cout <<a[i][j];
    cout << endl;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes I Edited This Part!